# cx_freeze exe run infinite time whithout stopping

Tags: python, linux, cx-freeze

Adter creating an exe with cx-freeze python 3.6 , in windows works fine but in linux it run infite times without stopping even i put just print('hello word') it just keep printing hello world without stopping.

Comment: Please provide a [example].

Comment: I guess the problem is just when importing NLTK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem caused by joblib, use :
scikit-learn==0.21.1
joblib==0.11

Answer (score 0):

Cx_freze uses files from Python instalation on your pc to create executable. So you can only make exe for system you currently working on. You cant make linux exe on windows and vice versa. Its interesting it run at all.

Comment: i am not making linux exe from windows, i am making the exe for windows in windows os and linux exe using docker, solution as i mentionend was chaning version of those libs scikit-learn==0.21.1 joblib==0.11